# How to display List of images in two columns and number of rows

Tags: iphone

In my project i have list of images i have to display them in two columns and number of rows How can i do this can any one help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a custom `UITableViewCell` that has two `UIImageView`s (as subviews) in it. Easiest way would be to do this through interface builder.